# Is there a way to in Big Query to pull data where there is Timestamp between yesterday at 5pm and today at 6am?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am pulling scan data for any scan that started between "yesterday" at 5pm and "today" at 6am. Currently, my WHERE statement is, for example:

```
and SCAN_START between '2023-09-06 17:00:00' and '2023-09-07 06:00:00'
```

I want to know if there is a way to use `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_DATE()-1` in this in any way so I don't have to manually change the date each time.

I tried to separate date in one line and time in another line, but that pulled pretty much the entire day's worth of scans and not really between the time I specified, which is what I imagined would happen.

Comment: What time zone are you interested in? You should basically work out the timestamp of "yesterday at 5pm" and "today at 6am" in the time zone you're interested in (bearing in mind the possibility of time zones skipping over one of those...) and then issue the query with those conditions. (While you *may* be able to do the time zone conversion within the SQL itself, I suspect it's significantly simpler to work that out in the code that's issuing the query. That may say more about my ability to work clearly in SQL though...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The data is converted to UTC time on the server already and I have the conversion already happening to the time zone(s) needed.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for `DATETIME` types, but there are corresponding methods for `TIMESTAMP` as well.

You can use [DATETIME_TRUNC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_trunc) and [CURRENT_DATETIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#current_datetime) to get the beginning of today (00:00:00), then use [DATETIME_SUB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_sub) and [DATETIME_ADD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_add) to offset your desired hours.

```
where scan_start between
    datetime_sub(datetime_trunc(current_datetime, day), interval 7 hour)
    and
    datetime_add(datetime_trunc(current_datetime, day), interval 6 hour)
```